# Creating InputProcessor for PerspectiveCamera on Android Libgdx

Tags: java, android, input, libgdx

I am trying to create an InputProcessor that will do many things. I have a touchpad set up that I am trying to move the camera along the x and y axes.

```
tBounds = new Sprite(Assets.touchpadBounds);
tBounds.setSize(tBounds.getWidth() * scale, tBounds.getHeight() * scale);
tKnob = new Sprite(Assets.touchpad);
tKnob.setSize(tKnob.getWidth() * scale, tKnob.getHeight() * scale);
touchpad = new Skin();
touchpad.add("boundary", tBounds);
touchpad.add("circle", tKnob);
touchpadStyle = new TouchpadStyle();
bounds = touchpad.getDrawable("boundary");
knob = touchpad.getDrawable("circle");
touchpadStyle.background = bounds;
touchpadStyle.knob = knob;
pad = new Touchpad(10, touchpadStyle);
stage.addActor(pad);
//Setting Bounds
pad.setBounds(width / 14, height / 10, tBounds.getHeight(),
tBounds.getWidth());

private void setKnobAction() {
    camera.position.set(camera.position.x + (pad.getKnobPercentX() * 0.1f),
            camera.position.y + 0,
            camera.position.z - (pad.getKnobPercentY() * 0.1f));
    camera.update();
}
```

The problem I am having with the setKnobAction() is that it moves the camera based on the initial direction it is facing. I am wanting it to move in the direction that it is currently facing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out. All I needed to do for forward and backward motion was to add or subtract the direction vector scaled by 1 to the position vector.

```
// To move forward
camera.position.add(camera.direction.scl(1f));
camera.update();

// To move backwards
camera.position.sub(camera.direction.scl(1f));
camera.update();

// To move to the right
Vector3 right = camera.direction.cpy().crs(Vector3.Y).nor();
camera.position.add(right.scl(1));
camera.update();

// To move to the left
Vector3 right = camera.direction.cpy().crs(Vector3.Y).nor();
camera.position.sub(right.scl(1));
camera.update();
```

To strafe (move to the left or right while the camera is facing forward) I needed to add or subtract the cross-product between the camera's direction vector and the camera's up vector.

Comment: Ah okay, the `camera` allready got a `direction` Vector. That makes it a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that you move the `camera` relativ to the worlds axis.
If you rotate your camera, the worlds axis stay the same, only the cameras direction vector changes.
Therefor you need to move your `camera` relativ to its direction vector.

I guess before playing arround with `PerspectiveCamera` and 3D in general you should read a few tutorials.
[Here](http://www-rohan.sdsu.edu/~stewart/cs583/LearningXNA3_lects/Lect15_Ch11_CreateFirstPersonCamera.html) is a tutorial, which describes a `FirstPersonCamera`.

Basicly you need to store a normalized direction Vector for the camera:

```
Vector3 direction = new Vector3(1, 0, 0); //You are looking in x-Direction
```

If you rotate, you need to rotate this Vector arround the worlds Y-Axis or the `camera`s Up-Axis (depends on the situation, explained in the linked tutorial):

```
direction.rotate(Vector3.Y, degrees).nor(); // Not sure if "nor()" is needed, it limits the length to 1, as it only gives the direction, not the speed.
```

To go foreward you simply need to add the direction Vector scaled by the speed to the position.

```
camera.position.add(direction.scl(speed))
```

After that you need to reset the `direction`s length by calling `nor()` again.

Hope it helps.

Comment: When I do this nothing happens.

Comment: Did you call `camera.update()`? This is only pseudo-code to give you some hints, the actual code is up to you. If you don't know how to implement it, i guess you are not ready for 3D yet...